# Selecting the next element with a given class from an element specified in code with jQuery

Tags: jquery, onclick, jquery-selectors

I've tried loads of options now!

I have a set of elements which contain thumbnails, created by an ASP Repeated and dynamically rendered to a page by an AJAX load, within them are some icons which when clicked enlarge an image.

The repeated HTML looks like this:

```
    <div class="prodImgContainer">
        <img src="*url*" id="*id*" class="itemImages" />
        <div class="imgControl">
            <span class="tinyIcons tinyDelete imgDelete" id="delete*id*"></span>
            <br />
            <span class="tinyIcons tinyZoom imgZoom" id="zoom*id*"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So, when you anything with the class `imgZoom` it fires the enlargement. This is done by a standard function which I have in place for loading modal windows.

```
    $('.imgZoom').live('click', function () {
        var prodId = $('#productId').val();
        var thisImage = ($(this).attr('id').replace('zoom', '')).replace('-tb', '');
        var img = $("<img />").addClass('nextImg').attr('id', 'thisImg' + thisImage).attr('src', '*BASE URL *' + prodId + '/' + thisImage + '.jpg').load(function () {
            if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
                alert('broken image!');
            } else {
                $("#largeImgContainer").empty();
                $('#showImg').click();
                $("#largeImgContainer").css('display', 'none').append(img).delay('1000').fadeIn('slow');
            };
        });
    });
```

The above code loads the enlarged image into an existing container.

Now... I want to be able to trigger a `click` event on the next `imgZoom` element by clicking the image which is created.

The calling element is no longer in the code though, so I am trying to do it like this:

```
    $('.nextImg').live('click', function () {
        var nextImage = ($(this).attr('id').replace('thisImg', '')).replace('-tb', '');
        $('#zoom' + nextImage + '-tb').next('.nextImg').click();
    });
```

Here, I am able to determine the ID of the element which was originally clicked to open up this image

I am then expecting `$('#zoom' + nextImage + '-tb').next('.nextImg').click();` to find that element, then find the next one with the class `nextImg` and click it

But it doesnt work... what am I missing?

Comment: I've made the same mistake myself, but `.next()` doesn't work that way. What it does is return the element that is immediately after the current element in the DOM **if** it matches the selector, otherwise it returns no elements.

Answer (score 0):

`next()` only returns the next element in the DOM (the elemement that is immediatly after it), you could do

```
  //this gets the DOM element
  var nextImg = $('#zoom' + nextImage + '-tb').nextAll('.nextImg')[0];
  //wrap this in jQuery and click it
  $(nextImg).click();
```

Taken from the docs

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the
>   .next() method allows us to search through the immediately following
>   sibling of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery
>   object from the matching elements.
>
> The method optionally accepts a selector expression of the same type
>   that we can pass to the $() function. If the immediately following
>   sibling matches the selector, it remains in the newly constructed
>   jQuery object; otherwise, it is excluded.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to attach the click to the dynamically created image element to trigger a click on the next imgZoom element, i.e. something like:

```
...
$("#largeImgContainer").empty();
$('#showImg').click();
$("#largeImgContainer").css('display', 'none').append(img).delay('1000').fadeIn('slow');

// here 'this' refers to the imgZoom element that was clicked
var nextElement = $(this).next('.imgZoom'); 
img.click(function() {
    nextElement.click(); // trigger the click
});
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made the same mistake myself, but .next() doesn't work that way. What it does is return the element that is immediately after the current element in the DOM **only if** it matches the selector, otherwise it returns no elements.

If you want the first element that comes after the currently selected element in the DOM that matches a specific selector, you could use something like this:

```
$('#zoom' + nextImage + '-tb').nextAll('.nextImg:first').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what you want, there are differences between your words and your code.

Maybe instead this line

```
$('#zoom' + nextImage + '-tb').next('.nextImg').click();
```

this would work:

```
$('#zoom' + nextImage + '-tb').parents('.prodImgContainer').next('.prodImgContainer').find('.imgZoom').click();
```

What I did not understand: the usage of '-tb' - where is it part of the id and where not? Why did you call .next('.nextImg')? I thought you wanted to click the next imgZoom element. In your code only the (single) image in largeImgContainer has the class nextImg.

Answer (score 0):

Argh!!

None of the above worked, but thanks for the help.

I ended up creating an array of images and passing the position through so the next image click would open the file in the next position in the array.